# Ten commands say to kill is wrong so why did God tell the people to kill the man who gathered sticks on the Sabbath?

Tags: old-testament, ten-commandments

In Numbers there is the story of the man who gathered sticks on the Sabbath and then God commanded the people to kill the man. However the 10 commandments make it clear that to kill is wrong. 
I understand why this man was to lose to his life but not why God would have people do it, people also instructed not to kill.

Then the Lord said to Moses, “The man shall surely be put to death; all the congregation shall stone him with stones outside the camp.”
Numbers 15:32-36

Comment: You realize that keeping the Sabbath is in the same line of commands as "do not kill", right? Do you believe that God cannot set punitive measures? Also, realize that a modern translation is "murder", not "kill". Murder is wanton and unjustified, kill is generic, in our modern tongue. In centuries past, "kill" was the same as "murder", and "slay" was generic.

Comment: In regards to the on-topic nature of this post, consider this site policy: [We can't handle the truth](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3527). This question will likely be closed. It's also a duplicate question: [Thou shall not kill?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17776)

Comment: @fredsbend thanks for your response! Yes I understand that of course God can set punitive measures my question though is why would God have people who are to obey the commandments take the mans life? Maybe you answered that in explaining the difference between murder and kill but I'm still a little confused there. Thanks I appreciate it.

Comment: @fredsbend that question discusses a more general act of killing in which God commands them to destroy certain nations which is not exactly what I'm shooting for although that does help answer my question some thanks.

Comment: @Nathaniel that post actually answered my question if think. I understand the difference between murder and kill now. Thanks for commenting that.

Answer (score 0):

Even though God said in the Mosaic that thou shall not kill but in the book of Numbers 15:32-36 He ordered Moses to make all the  congregation to stone outside the camp. This situation does not break that law because God himself is the Author of that law. He is the maker of humankind and at that time the of Israel were under law but not Grace.
Even the Bible says in the book 1 Sam 2:30-31(NIV):

30 "Therefore the Lord, the God of Israel, declares: 'I promised that your house and your father's house would minister before me forever.' But now the Lord declares: 'Far be it from me! Those who honor me I will honor, but those who despise me will be disdained".

This means that was what He want to do and He made and it doesn't go against any of His law given to his people. He is All-Knowing and all wisdom belong to him.

Comment: Thanks that definitely helps and makes sense I think understanding the difference between kill and murder and how the translation from Greek and Hebrew did not actually mean to kill anything or anyone under any circumstance is wrong but was more specific answers my question. It does make sense though too that they were under law not grace at the time and God has control over the rules he set in place.

Comment: Welcome Donkor! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you showed, with sources, that it doesn't merely reflect your own analysis.  Here we focus on the teachings of Christian traditions and groups, not individual interpretations.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).