# How do those who believe in the immortality of the soul explain Leviticus 21:11?

Tags: exegesis, souls, leviticus, immortality

### How do those who believe in the immortality of the soul explain Leviticus 21:11?

> Leviticus 21:11 Hebrew OT: Westminster Leningrad Codex
>
> וְעַ֛ל כָּל־**|נַפְשֹׁ֥ת מֵ֖ת|** לֹ֣א יָבֹ֑א לְאָבִ֥יו וּלְאִמֹּ֖ו לֹ֥א
>   יִטַּמָּֽא׃
>
> He shall not go in to any ***dead bodies*** nor make himself unclean,
>   even for his father or for his mother (ESV)

The ESV reads "dead bodies". However, the Hebrew literally reads "dead soul."

Comment: Since your question presumes the translation is incorrect, hermeneutics.stackExchange.com would be more appropriate.  Keep in mind all of these 21 translations use the word body or person.  http://biblehub.com/leviticus/21-11.htm  On either Christianity.SE or hermeneutics.SE , you'll need some significant justification for the alternate translation and deciding "body" is not an acceptable translation.

Comment: You actually have a good point. How do I transfer the question to hermeneutics.stackExchange.com?

Comment: Since there are no other responses or comments yet, probably post the question in hermeneutics.  Possibly post the link in an answer, then close or delete this question?  Better answers need a moderator.

Comment: I asked about closing this question   [Appropriate Resolution for off topic question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6069)

Comment: A related question about this text might work on [hermeneutics.se], but as worded _this exact_ question would not be a good fit there. Asking for  the views of a specific group is a question format we use here on C.SE but not on BH.SE. If you want to migrate it please [edit] to make it an appropriate question for the other site. Meanwhile I don't see a problem with it staying here.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>To my knowledge no serious theologian who doesn't believe in the immortality of the soul uses examples such as Lev 21:11 as proof-texts, so those who do (believe in the immortality of the soul) have not frequently felt the need to defend it on such a charge. Nevertheless, mainstream scholarship provides ample explanation of the lexical phenomenon.</sub>

---

The claim is made in the question:

> the Hebrew literally reads "dead soul."

Although it's true that "soul" is the traditional rendering of *nephesh*, the term rarely (if ever) means "soul" in the specialized sense that it is used in Christian theology.<sup>1</sup>

> The more vaguely and naively ["soul"] is used, the more correct and appropriate this translation becomes.<sup>2</sup>

Lexicons all agree that "soul" is applicable in a minority of cases; the only real disagreement is whether it is *ever* applicable, and nobody counts Lev 21:11 among the possibilities. Instead, along with a handful of other passages (Lev. 19:28; 22:4; Num. 5:2; 6:11; 9:6, 7, 10, 11, 13; and Hag. 2:13), this usage is glossed by HALOT (the standard modern lexicon of Biblical Hebrew) as:

> deceased person, corpse.

We could leave it at that, but for the sake of thoroughness I will point out that the venerable [TDOT](https://www.eerdmans.com/Products/CategoryCenter.aspx?CategoryId=SE!TDOT) rejects this definition ([Horst Seebass](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_Seebass)). To understand why, we return to the OP's suggested translation "dead soul[s],"<sup>3</sup> henceforth "dead *naphshot*" (= plural *nephes*). In fact, a more fastidiously literal translation would be "*naphshot* of [one] being dead" or "*naphshot* of a corpse". At this point we can provide an alternative response to the OP's query:

> *nepeš* cannot refer to the corpse itself, but only to something associated with it.<sup>2</sup>

Although he "spiritualizes" *nephesh* in some sense, then ("vital force"), Seebass points out that all of these examples, which describe the uncleanness that results from proximity to the "*naphshot* of the dead", still do not carry the sense suggested in the question:

> "Rich and abundant though this use of *nepeš* for life is, we must not fail to observe that the *nepeš* is never given the meaning of an indestructible core of being, in contradistinction to the physical life, and even capable of living when cut off from that life." We may therefore assume that even in death the vital force is something uncanny, belonging solely to God, which God’s people should not come near.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sub>1. The translation "soul" probably came about by way of the Greek *psyche*. See also, [this Q&A](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/25184/13677) which revolved around the same misunderstanding.</sub>

<sub>2. Horst Seebass. נפש, [*Theological Dictionary of the Old Testment*](https://www.eerdmans.com/Products/CategoryCenter.aspx?CategoryId=SE!TDOT) Ed. Johannes Botterweck, Helmer Ringgren, Heinz-Joef Fabry, Trans. John T. Wills  (Eerdmans, 1974) Volume 9, p. 512ff.</sub>

<sub>3. I presume this was intended, as the word *nephesh* is plural in Hebrew and in translation.</sub>

<sub>4. Seebass, p. 516, quoting Hans Walter Wolff.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The Hebrew נפש can also be translated as "person", as in:

> Genesis 14:21 (ESV)
>
> > *And the king of Sodom said to Abram, “Give me the **persons**, but take the goods for yourself.”*

This ambiguity is also reflected in the Greek Septuagint translation (undertaken by Alexandrian Jews), which uses the word ψυχή (*psyche*)  - translated as "soul", "life", persons" and otherwise in the ESV.

Answer (score 0):

To some, the term "soul" refers collectively to the physical body and the spirit.  For an example look at terms used by commercial travel.  "How many souls aboard?"  That would be an odd question if bodies themselves weren't part of the equation.  Thus, when a body dies, that's also the end of the soul until the spirit is reunited with the body after the Resurrection.

Comment: Welcome! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you showed, with sources, that it doesn't merely reflect your own analysis – is this actually how advocates of the immortality of the soul explain Leviticus 21:11?  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).