# Does the doctrine of Sola Scriptura prohibit the use of empirical information to understand the bible?

Tags: sola-scriptura

As an example, what about examining Jesus' interaction with the Roman Centurion using historical documents explaining how the Roman Army was run?

Answer (score 10):

I will answer, because (as you may have noticed from my other answers) I'm about as "Sola Scriptura" as they come.

### No.

Basically, we believe that Scripture was given by God as the **standard** for His people to use in determining truth.

> All Scripture is inspired by God and profitable for teaching, for reproof, for correction, for training in righteousness; so that the man of God may be adequate, equipped for every good work. [**- 2 Tim 3:16-17**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Tim%203:16-17&version=NASB)

(See also [Titus 1:9](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Titus%201:9&version=NASB).)  Since Scripture adequately equips you to correct false doctrine, that implies it is **the** standard of truth.

**So the point is this:** If a person teaches something [**contrary**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gal%201:8-9,%20Matt%204:1-11&version=NASB) to Scripture, they are **wrong**.

That is not to say that everything *outside* of scripture is wrong (or "not from God")... just everything ***contrary***.  Therefore we **reject** any teaching which opposes what we **know** (based on Scripture);

> We are destroying speculations and every lofty thing raised up against the knowledge of God, and we are taking every thought captive to the obedience of Christ  [**- 2 Cor 10:5**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%2010:5&version=NASB)

So the only safe bet is to use Scripture as the **foundation** of all of your doctrine.  *(Additional elements include [understanding](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Tim%201:3-8&version=NASB) the Scriptures, being [led by the Spirit](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2014:26,%2016:13&version=NASB), recognizing the [teachers](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Eph%204:4-16,%201%20Cor%2012:29,%20Jas%203:1&version=NASB) God has given, etc.)*

So as I said, the answer to your question is "no."  In fact, studying history is ***incredibly*** helpful in understanding Scripture.  *(When preparing for sermons, I have often found the NIV Archaeological Study Bible very helpful in bridging contexts between the ancient world and our own.)*

I think the big distinction between Sola Scriptura and opposing views is that if the Bible says "X" and an external source says "Y", we consider the external source rubbish, whereas others may attempt to reconcile the two, sometimes by re-translating the Bible.

Comment: I can't imagine someone saying that scripture is literally the only possible source of truth. To take an extreme example, if I want to know if it's raining outside, I don't consult scripture: I look out the window. As Jas3.1 says, an advocate of Sola Scriptura would say that anything that contradicts scripture must be false. Where it gets debatable is on something claiming to be revelation from God outside of scripture: some say that the Bible is the complete revelation of God, others would allow for additional revelation.