# Was Jesus an adherent to 'Sola Scriptura'?

Tags: life-of-jesus, exegesis, sola-scriptura, epistemology

Adherents to *Sola Scriptura* basically believe that Scripture should be the foundation of all doctrine.  *(NOTE: That is not to say that outside sources cannot be used to aide us in understanding the text - [see here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/7759/1548).)*

Based on what we know about Jesus from Scripture, could Jesus be considered an adherent to this philosophy?

Comment: Jesus is God. He can't be an 'adherent' of any doctrine.

Comment: How can Jesus adhere to a scripture which wasn't written yet?  So then... if it WAS written would he adhere to it?  Probably not for reasons suggested by DJClayworth.  Did Jesus "adhere" to the old testament?  No and any person practicing Judaism would tall you that Jesus did not fulfill the prophesies that they were expecting and from his own accord, demanded change.

Comment: @TheFreemason Have you ever read the Gospels? Jesus' entire life, ministry, and teachings were rooted in the Old Covenant Scriptures. I'm obviously not asking if Jesus adhered to later NT writings that weren't even written yet.

Comment: then it is not Sola Scriptura - which is for the bible.  And if Jesus continued following the old testament (and demanded his followers to do it as well) then we'd still be burning lambs.

Comment: @TheFreemason I have never heard anyone say that the Old Testament was not Scripture until the NT was complete. Where are you getting these ideas from? To my knowledge the orthodox position (at least in the Protestant tradition) has always been that the writings were Scripture from the moment they was written. Are you coming from a church background that believes it's only "Scripture" because the church said so?

Comment: @Jas3.1 can you show me were the term Sola Scriptura existed before the canonization?  Maybe I'm wrong (I'm not afraid to accept being wrong), however I think you should consider rewording your question to ask if Jesus followed the laws of the Torah. Which then, Matthew 5:17 will be quoted.  When Christians think of the Scriptures (Sola Scriptura) they think of the Gospels.  That is not what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you could even ask this on Judiasm.SE - did Jesus obey the Torah.  Obviously they would say no or state that they really do not know what Jesus did or didn't do as he's really not part of their history.  Just a thought though.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if Jesus were to only follow the Torah then he would have been a Sadducee instead of Essene.

Comment: This certainly looks like a "truth question" and one that begs for opinions rather than the doctrinal positions of any particular denomination. It's from an earlier era of this site, and doesn't pass muster under current site guidelines.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is simply: No.
One way to prove it, is to take the verse where Jesus says:

**"Whoever listens to you listens to me. Whoever rejects you rejects me. And whoever rejects me rejects the one who sent me."** (Luke 10:16)

That means, that whatever the apostles say, is Jesus' teaching. Then we can take Paul's words to the Thessalonians in chapter 2 verse 15:

**"So then, brothers, stand firm and hold to the teachings we passed on to you, whether by word of mouth or by letter."** (NIV)

This is saying to hold to the scriptures *and* oral teaching. One link that might prove helpful is [here](http://www.calledtocommunion.com/2011/03/sola-scriptura-vs-the-magisterium-what-did-jesus-teach/), asking: "Sola Scriptura vs. the Magisterium: What did Jesus Teach?". One that deals with just Sola Scriptura can be found [here](http://www.catholicbasictraining.com/apologetics/coursetexts/1n.htm).

[One link](http://explaining-the-catholic-faith.com/id49.html) that might have an answer, says:

**Did not Jesus say, "Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, teaching them to observe all that I have commanded you. . . ." [Matthew 28:19] Of course this admonishes them to teach; it says nothing about writing. And the Bible itself says nothing about it being the sole source of God’s revelation.**

Anyways, that is just my opinion and it may be a little biased. One thing to think about, is that for the first couple hundred years, there was no "New Testament". The last of the gospels by John, was written by A.D 85 or later.

I agree with you that:

**If a person teaches something contrary to Scripture, they are wrong.**

But sometimes things may seem contrary and actually be true to each-other. [Here](http://www.ecclesia.org/truth/contradictions.html) is a link that explains some things that seem to contradict each-other in the bible, but just need a little explanation (I know that that is both sources from the bible, but it is basically the same).

And just to let you know, I'm *not* Roman Catholic.

Comment: You might enjoy reading my response here also: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/8339/1304

Answer (score 2):

We need to start by bearing in mind that during Jesus lifetime there is no set Bible as such. There are collections of scrolls in synagogues but the ones that would eventually be considered canonical by modern Judaism were not set at that time (canonicity in Judaism slowly distilled between ~200BC and ~200AD). You would get different stuff in different places, some were widely accepted e.g. the Torah, some version of Isaiah etc. others not so much - e.g. the writings. In this context perhaps it is difficult to define what Sola Scriptura really means.

The Biblical Jesus is well-versed in the OT (Luke 2:41-52). However, often presents the anti-thesis to these Biblical texts in his own teaching "You have heard it said  but I say to you ".

On the whole it seems pretty unlikely that Jesus subscribed to Sola Scriptura as we understand it.

Answer (score -1):

Jesus was tempted thrice by the Devil and he responded three words that defeated the Devil: "IT IS WRITTEN." ~ Matthew 4:1-11

Jesus never did refer to oral traditions in a positive way.Rather, every time he defends truth he refers to the scriptures:

> Thus **you nullify the word of God by your tradition that you have
>   handed down.** And you do many things like that." (Mark 7:13)
>
> "What is **written** in the **Law**? **How does it read to you?**" (Luke
>   10:26)
>
> Jesus said to them, "Is this not the reason you are mistaken, that
>   **you do not understand the Scriptures** or the power of God? (Mark 12:24)
>
> But Jesus answered and said to them, "You are mistaken, **not
>   understanding the Scriptures** nor the power of God. (Matthew 22:29)
>
> "**What then is this that is written**: 'The stone which the builders
>   rejected, This became the chief corner stone'? (Luke 20:17)
>
> **"How then will the Scriptures be fulfilled**, which say that it must happen this way?" (Matthew 26:54)

Timothy knew the Holy Scriptures since childhood. What is this Holy Scriptures? Is it the 39 books? Is it the Septuagint or is it the Hebrew Texts?

**One thing is for sure.There existed the Holy Scriptures that is God-breathed and Timothy knew it since childhood according to Paul.**

> 15 **And that from a babe thou hast known the sacred writings** which
>   are able to make thee wise unto salvation through faith which is in
>   Christ Jesus.
>
> 16 **Every scripture** inspired of God is also profitable for
>   teaching, for reproof, for correction, for instruction which is in
>   righteousness.
>
> 17 That the man of God may be complete, furnished completely **unto**
>   **every good work**.
>
> > 2 Timothy 3:15-17 (ASV)

It says "EVERY good work" not "SOME good work."Hence, Sola Scriptura (Scripture alone), showcasing the Scriptures as the only authoritative revelation God has given to his church for teaching and deciding matters of faith [*doctrines*] and morals [*ethics*].

What this shows is that **Sola Scriptura** existed in the first century. Jesus is the *model* whom Paul followed on this principle and this is substantiated by this instance recorded in 2 Timothy 3:15-17.

Comment: 2 Timothy 3:14  always left out of a Protestant explanation or defense.
14 "But continue thou in the things which thou hast learned and hast been assured of, knowing of whom thou hast learned them."

Comment: @Marc, Paul was saying that Timothy knew from whom he had learned and that's from those who held onto the apostolic teaching.2 Timothy 3:14 does say that we should have a "list of bishops"( apostolic succession) but rather, of "teaching succession" ("continue in the things which you have learned and have been assured of" i.e. apostolic teaching).

Comment: it is interesting that you brough up bishops. Did I suggest 2 Tim 3:14 addresses Bishops? I only suggested that Sola Scriptura was not the only thing mentioned to Timothy,a Bishop ordained by Paul, as authoritative,he mentions as you suggest the teaching authority of the Curch to maintain orthodoxy i.e. The magestarium"Continue in what you have learned" They did not learn TULIP any part of it. They did not learn the 5 Sola's,   Every part of it is a deviation to the Gospel of Jesus Christ. Biblically Speaking.
James 2:24  "You see that a man is JUSTIFIED by WORKS and NOT by FAITH ALONE"

Comment: @Marc  It's interesting you said this" "I only suggested that Sola Scriptura was not the only thing mentioned to Timothy."Well, you just mishandled James 2:24, it talked about James' "brethren", that is, those who HAVE BEEN SAVED by grace through faith alone (cf:Ephesians 2:8, James 2:1).

Comment: Do brethren need to be justified a second time?  If they do that makes sense, or are they getting more justified. Are there degrees in justification?   These "Bretheren" according to you already having accepted Jesus as thier personal lord and savior, are learning how thier works, done after thier salvation, has now  (finally) justified them?  Completing their transition from unsaved to saved by some act of charity sealing the deal?  Why do those who "have been saved" need to receive further justification above and beyond Faith?  Ephesians does not say "Alone" you have added that.

Comment: @Marc, in James 2:24, man is justified (declared righteous) in whose sight? The sight of men (v.15-16 Suppose a brother or a sister is without clothes and daily food. If one of you says to them, “Go in peace; keep warm and well fed,” but does nothing about their physical needs, what good is it?).Faith alone does not show God's righteousness in us: "Let your light shine before men..." (Matthew 5:16).What? When Paul said "faith" and "not of works" in Ephesians 2:8-9, it highly implies "faith alone."

Comment: The answer "whose sight".Is God's sight. Why else would it effect our salvation? Jam2:14 "can his faith save him"it does not say,"can his faith reveal Gods rightousness" This passage as well as many others in the bible point to the need for works corresponding to an obedience of faith when entering into the Grace of our Lord Jesus Christ. To be "In Christ" is to complete what is lacking in Christs suffering. Col 1:24 and to enter into his covenant via the ordinances prescribed by Christ in his sacraments. What is difficult for you is that the word of God directly challenges your beliefs.

Comment: making is necessary for you add words like "Alone" "TULIP" "Secret Rapture" Sola Sciptura" and countless other abominations leading souls away from Christs Church.

Comment: @Marc, mere babble.

Comment: That is precisely what Martin Luther Said when he refered to the writings of James as"an epistle of Straw" Your argument is with James not with me. Mathew 5:14“You are the salt of the earth, but if salt has lost its taste, how shall its saltiness be restored? It is no longer good for anything except to be thrown out and trampled under people's feet"There is an emptyness in the protestantism, a faith that holds true so much, what's missing is the Worship reserved only for God, and the gifts that Christ has left for his Church which have all been rejected in favor of religious autonomy.

Comment: @Marc, Was Luther alone who doubted James as canonical? I don't think so.Early church history shows that Luther wasn't the first in that line of reasoning.

Comment: Interesting that there where other professed Christians who didn't recognized the word of God?  What heresies did they teach?  After the authenticity was recognized by early Church Councils, The epistle of James remained unchallenged until the Protestant Reformation.  When researching Biblical history, you may wish to consult those motivated by Cultureral pressures, such as American Evangelicalism, or, you can consult the Chruch who assembled the books in the Bible in the first place, the church that was there and was faithful to the Apostles.

Answer (score -7):

Protestants are going to say yes. Catholics are going to say no.

I presume any Christian is going to consider this question equivalent to, "Is the doctrine of Sola Scriptura true?" I mean, who is going to say, "I am a Christian, I believe Jesus to be the all-knowing God made flesh ... but when on this very important point he said X, he was completely wrong."

Comment: This is a very different question from "is Sola Scriptura true?"

Comment: How is it different? If you're a Christian, I think by definition that means that at the very least you have a very high respect for Jesus Christ. So if someone convinced you that Jesus did not believe in Sola Scriptura, you would have to have a strong bias against it, and vice versa.

Comment: Jesus is God. If Jesus says something, it's God's word, whether it's written in scripture or not.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't understand that last point. I mean, I agree that it's true, but what statements has Jesus made that you and I know about that aren't in Scripture? Are you saying that Jesus rejected Sola Scriptura in some statement that is not in scripture? Or are you saying that Jesus could give a further revelation beyond what is in scripture, and this would be as authoritative as scripture? I'd say sort of: If it was accepted, it would then by definition be part of scripture. If it was rejected as a fake or hoax, then it wouldn't be authoritative.

Comment: OK, Jay. Imagine you are a disciple of Jesus, circa 30AD. You listen to Jesus preaching. Is what he says authoritative? Yes, absolutely. Is it in scripture? No, because the New Testament isn't written down yet. The only scripture is the Old Testament. If you are a follower of 'sola scriptura' then you must reject his words, because they are not in scripture. And if Jesus were a follower of sola scriptura then he must reject them also. Which would be stupid.

Comment: I'm not going to make further replies here. If you want to know more, please create a chat room.

Comment: Ok then, I'll make a final reply and leave it at that also. I think your last post is a bit of a strawman argument, perhaps based on an imprecise wording of the doctrine. The point of Sola Scriptura is not that its advocates would reject words of Christ not recorded in the Bible, but that they believe that all doctrine must be based on revelation from God and not human reasoning. It was a response to the Catholic doctrine that the writings of the Church Fathers have equal or near-equal weight with scripture.