# Who Killed the giant Goliath?

Tags: david, 1-samuel, 2-samuel

We read in 1 Samuel 17: "David killed Goliath"

> And as he talked with them, behold, there came up the champion, the
>   Philistine of Gath, Goliath by name, out of the ranks of the
>   Philistines, and spake according to the same words: and David heard
>   them. **1 Samuel 17:23 ASV**

(...)

> Then David ran, and stood over the
>   Philistine, and took his sword, and drew it out of the sheath thereof,
>   and slew him, and cut off his head therewith. And when the Philistines
>   saw that their champion was dead, they fled. **1 Samuel 17:51 ASV**

But we read in 2 Samuel 21: "Elhanan killed the giant Goliath"

> And there was again war with the Philistines at Gob; and Elhanan the
>   son of Jaareoregim the Beth-lehemite slew Goliath the Gittite, the
>   staff of whose spear was like a weaver’s beam. **2 Samuel 21:19 ASV**

So, who killed Goliath?

Comment: The duplicate was poorly titled.  I updated it to be clearer.

Comment: Personally, I'd rather close the other one as a duplicate of this.  I think this wording with far more clear and concise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [article](http://carm.org/bible-difficulties/joshua-esther/who-killed-goliath-david-or-elhanan) the discrepancy is most likely a simple copyist error of a single letter causing confusion.  David killed Goliath, and Elhannan killed Goliath's brother. 1 Chronicles 20:5 (which repeats this verse) says:

> 5 And there was again war with the Philistines, and Elhanan the son of Jair struck down Lahmi the brother of Goliath the Gittite, the shaft of whose spear was like a weaver's beam.

There are [no serious biblical inerrantists](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/from-a-fundamentalist-standpoint-what-does-the-phrase-inspired-infallible-in/9947#9947) (and I do not consider myself an inerrantist at all) that say that there are no copy errors in the bible. Inerrancy is only ascribed to the original manuscripts. A quick reading of a good [apparatus](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8466/how-do-i-track-the-history-of-changes-to-a-given-verses-actual-text-how-do-i-d) will reveal this to be a common (and minor) copy error, as understood even by an inerrantist.