# What are the name(s) of the archaeological artifact(s)/scroll(s) where the New Testament was based?

Tags: new-testament, archaeology

I'm wondering about the roots of the New Testament.
What are the name(s) of the archaeological artifact(s)/scroll(s) where the New Testament was based?

Comment: There are thousands of different copies of the New Testament writings--actually over 5000.  Additionally, virtually all of the New Testament appears in quotations from the first few centuries afterward.  So, it is not one complete scroll, as the New Testament was not brought together as one until later.  As such, there are many manuscripts--not just one.  Remember that the New Testament was written over a period of 50-60 years by several different authors--Matthew, Mark, Luke, John, Paul, Peter, James, Jude and whoever wrote Hebrews.

Comment: I re-wrote the question.

Comment: Welcome to SE Christianity, Abel. I find your question a little bit confusing. Perhaps you could try rewording it for better clarity. The New Testament is based on any number of manuscripts, Alexandrian and Byzantine, but the two main schools of Bible translation scholars side with either the "Majority Text" of Erasmus from 1516, which gave rise to the King James Version (AV or KJV) or the Critical Text "the New Textus Receptus") based on the Nestle/Aland Greek New Testament, which gave rise to the modern RSV, NEB, NASB, and NIV.

Comment: When you are asking what base manuscripts are extant, you need to consult an apparatus to put together what you are looking at.

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9934/what-is-manuscript-evidence-and-how-is-it-useful would also be highly related

Comment: based on the above comments, I think there is no point of pursuing this question because it might need a very long list to be able to choose the right answer. The question [How do I track the history of changes to a given verse's actual text? How do I discover it's “lineage”?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8466/how-do-i-track-the-history-of-changes-to-a-given-verses-actual-text-how-do-i-d) is relatively close to this one. I may request someone to close this one. Thank you guys.