# What is the name of this fragment? Where can I find more?

Tags: archaeology

According to [this article](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2015/01/20/scientists-claim-the-hidden-papyrus-uncovered-inside-this-mummy-mask-could-end-up-being-the-oldest-copy-of-a-christian-gospel-ever/?utm_source=TheBlaze.com&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=story&utm_content=scientists-claim-the-hidden-papyrus-uncovered-inside-this-mummy-mask-could-end-up-being-the-oldest-copy-of-a-christian-gospel-ever) in The Blaze:

> The discovery of a small papyrus fragment containing words from the Book of Mark could end up being the earliest copy of a Christian gospel on record, according to experts. The biblical text, which came from Egypt, was reportedly placed on a sheet of papyrus before the document was recycled and used to create a mummy mask.

The article goes on to state several interesting "facts" about this Gospel of Mark fragment:

- It may date to 90AD, which would make it even older than [p52 - the oldest known fragment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31049/where-do-primary-sources-for-the-bible-reside/31051#31051)
- It is currently unpublished, although it may be published in 2015.
- Daniel Wallace has mentioned it

While I'm sure the historians will debate the scientific evidence, I have a much more simple question - what is it being called, and how will i be able to follow updates about its veracity?

And, if I wanted to see a copy of it, where would I go to find it?

Comment: My guess is that since it's apparently still the subject of nondisclosure agreements, you won't be able to find any information about it until first publication, whenever and wherever that is.

Comment: Although his findings have proved controversial among scholars, Thiede's dating of the Magdalene papyrus to even earlier in the first century than the fragment of Mark you refer to, they are at least worth consideration. See Wikipedia's article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magdalen_papyrus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with the [finder's website](http://www.craigaevans.com/) and [this article from The Gospel Coalition](http://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/mummy-mask-may-reveal-oldest-fragment-of-the-gospel-of-mark).

As to where to find more, Craig Evans might know.

Comment: Didn't think to look at his bio but yeah. My best bet.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that the papyrus is called "Oxyrhynchus Papyrus 5345".

It is now said to be not 1st century but 2nd or 3rd century:-

https://danielbwallace.com/2018/05/23/first-century-mark-fragment-update/

Answer (score 0):

The [article to which you linked](http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2015/01/20/scientists-claim-the-hidden-papyrus-uncovered-inside-this-mummy-mask-could-end-up-being-the-oldest-copy-of-a-christian-gospel-ever/?utm_source=TheBlaze.com&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=story&utm_content=scientists-claim-the-hidden-papyrus-uncovered-inside-this-mummy-mask-could-end-up-being-the-oldest-copy-of-a-christian-gospel-ever) cited [LiveScience](http://www.livescience.com/49489-oldest-known-gospel-mummy-mask.html).

Unfortunately, the LiveScience source merely says that it will be published in 2015. So, we'll have to wait for the answer then to know the name of the document.