# I ran across someone who claims the bible translation as we know it is wrong

Tags: bible, bible-translation

I ran across someone who claims the bible translation as we know is wrong. They claim the term Father should be replaced by Creator. And that the bible was contaminated by catholic scholar. is this true? Where there a complete manuscripts with the original text? thanks

To be more specific they said: The Catholics changed / translated the bible in a way to bring fourth a false word of God. The ORIGINAL scripts never refer to a " God the father" but God the Creator.

I quoted him

1 Corinthians 8:6

> But to us there is but one God, the Father, of whom are all things, and we in him; and one Lord Jesus Christ, by whom are all things, and we by him.

Galatians 4:4

> But when the fullness of the time was come, “God sent forth his Son”, made of a woman, made under the law”. Made of a woman.

John 20:17

> Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my Father:

Matthew 10:33

> But whosoever shall deny me (The Son) before men, him will I also deny before “MY” Father which is in heaven.

John 10:36

> ... I said, I am the Son of God

Mostly all the verse that are in the NT where Jesus says "MY Father"

So is his claim true? and where could I find the best original text that covers means Father is Father not creator. Thanks

Comment: I notice this question is almost exactly the same as your previous question that was closed https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92122/someone-said-the-bible-translation-are-wrong-the-word-father-should-be-creator If you believe it should be reopened, please edit that question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: I didn't see how to resubmit the orignail. I added more text and submited a new one. Sorry I was following intructions.  No i have not got an answer

Comment: No mini answers in the comments please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Someone claims] that the bible was contaminated by catholic scholars.

Extremely unlikely. Many translations, most of which are in very close agreement (notable exceptions include translations by JWs and LDS, both of which are considered heretical and decisively non-Christian — meaning they reject even the most basic of shared beliefs — by mainstream Christians), have been carried out by multiple denominations. Even the KJV was translated by Anglicans! The likelihood of such alterations remaining unnoticed for thousands of years is virtually nil.

> Where could I find the best original text?

[Where can I find scans of original Biblical manuscripts?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34099) lists several sources. You'll need to know Greek, however, and at some point you're trusting that the *language itself* hasn't been corrupted.

That said, given that the Greek uses "Πατρὸς" ("Patros"), and given how many words in multiple languages are floating around that clearly derive from this root and which either *mean* "father" or some term *related* to "fathers" (e.g. "patriarchy"), if the word *has* been corrupted somehow, it would represent a conspiracy of almost inconceivable magnitude.

> The ORIGINAL scripts never refer to a "God the father" but God the Creator.

First, to play a bit of "Devil's advocate"... Jesus referring to himself as "the Son" is totally plausible even if this claim is correct. There's also a certain extent of "does it matter?", since a father *is* in a sense a "creator" of his offspring.

**That said**... unless the meaning of "Patros" changed after the NT was written, *and* that change somehow spread throughout *other* existing languages (Latin, in particular) in such a way as to leave no trace, I don't see any plausible way in which such a claim could be true. You would *also* have to somehow account for other, less direct uses of parental imagery throughout the Scriptures, such as God's adoption of us as "children", inheritance, etc.

More likely the claimant is trying to deny a Biblical truth. The number of people, even "Christians", that deny one or more Biblical truths is exceedingly high, making that a *far* more plausible explanation.

> I ran across someone who claims the bible translation as we know is wrong

In short, unless they're talking about a translation *known* to be bad (Watchtower, Mormon, Passion, etc.), such claims are almost surely bogus. ESV and NASB are regarded by many as the "best" translations, albeit more literal and sometimes harder to read. There's another highly regarded one, though I forget which it is (possibly CSB?). NIV is generally considered "okay" but some feel it is slightly biased. To an extent, your preference is likely to depend on your specific theology. That said, if the majority of mainstream translations (in which I would include, besides the preceding, [N]KJV, [N]RSV, NET, NLT and possibly CEB) agree on a point, you can be pretty confident that point is correct.

Comment: What translation does LDS use that is bad?  I've never heard they had a problem with the OT or NT, just the Book of Mormon.

Comment: @PeterTurner, the Joseph Smith translation. Some info [here](https://carm.org/mormonism/the-joseph-smith-translation-of-the-bible-and-his-false-claim-to-prophethood/). JST and NWT have similar issues, namely, "translations" that have been deliberately altered in order to support (respectively) LDS or JW theology which are almost universally (that is, by Christians *other* than the LDS or JWs) agreed to be unsupported and incorrect. The Passion translation has similar issues. Essentially, such translations *are* guilty of the sorts of claims as in the question.

Answer (score -3):

We do not have the original manuscripts, all we have are copies of copies of copies.
Most of the things that were changed from the copies we do have, were grammatical changes that had little bearing on the text.

The major changes were mostly things added to the text at a later date.
In some places the male scribes and translators replaced the name of Mary Magdalene with "Martha" so that Mary wouldn't overshadow the male disciples.
The story of the woman caught in adultery was added later on.
The end of Mark was made longer. The original ending is the women at the empty tomb keeping the news of the resurrection to themselves.

To me, the Bible is just a book and shouldn't be taken to literally. The issues with our translations isn't that big a deal, the bigger issue is how most modern Christians interpret the Bible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).