# What are the arguments in favour of the 'beginning' at John 1:1 being the old beginning?

Tags: christology, genesis, gospel-of-john

The standard reading of John 1:1

"In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God."

is that the beginning - ἀρχῇ (archē) - refers to the old beginning, i.e., the beginning described in Genesis 1.

What are the main arguments in favour of the beginning at John 1:1 referring to the old beginning instead of the new beginning (i.e., the beginning of Jesus' (human) life or ministry)?

This question is a mirror of [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92108/what-are-the-arguments-in-favour-of-the-beginning-at-john-11-being-the-new-be).

Comment: What was the first creative act  by God?

Comment: John COULD have said "In eternity, the Word was with God, and the Word was God," but he did not. John did, however, elucidate John 1:1 later in his Gospel in chapter 8: “You are not yet fifty years old,” [the Jews] said to [Jesus], “and you have seen Abraham!” “'Very truly I tell you,' Jesus answered, 'before Abraham was born, I am!' At this, they picked up stones to stone him, but Jesus hid himself, slipping away from the temple grounds." Why did the Jews react so violently to Jesus' words? Because Jesus was claiming eternality AND echoing God's words to Moses: “I am who I am" (Ex 3:14).

Comment: @rhetorician Thanks for these comments - points certainly worth considering. I would add that John 8:58's grammar is ambiguous - it could even mean Abraham was coming to be in the future (!). Also, the 'I am' of Exodus 3:14 isn't 'ego eimi' in the Septuagint, it's ho on. It also doesn't work in the Hebrew. They could have been P.O.ed because he was claiming to be more important than Abraham, whom they revered (while he, on the other hand, had just called them liars, murderers, and sons of the Devil). So it's not clear to me John is elucidating 1:1 at 8:58, but this is the right tack IMO.

Answer (score 2):

First, there are no (good) arguments *against* it. John 1:1 is radically different than the start of the other Gospels, so "consistency" claims already fall flat. The argument that v6 must not represent a jump ahead in time is dodgy at best, as v6 is clearly starting a new thought. The later date of John's authorship also suggests that John may have been writing in response to early attempts to deny Christ's divinity, which is firmly established in many places¹.

Second, such an interpretation makes v3 inconsistent with the rest of scripture, and also... odd. Jesus is the Creator of... what, exactly (according to an interpretation that "beginning" here is something other than The Beginning)?

Compare:

| Hebrews 1:2 |
| --- |
| [God] has spoken to us by his Son [...] through whom also he created the world |

| 1 Corinthians 6:8b |
| --- |
| [there is] one Lord, Jesus Christ, through whom are all things and through whom we exist. |

| Colossians 1:16 |
| --- |
| For by [Christ] all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities — all things were created through Him and for Him. |

| Psalm 33:6a |
| --- |
| By the Word of the Lord the heavens were made |

Note that the greater context of Colossians 1 makes it clear that Paul is referring to Christ.

Thus, we have several passages, *even in the Old Testament* (when we consider John showing us that Christ is the Word; 1:1 and 1:14) that attest to all of Creation being accomplished *through Christ*. Why, then, would we think that John 1:3 is not meant to be consistent with these other passages? (Moreover, the passages in the Epistles that *Christ* specifically deny any notion that "the Word" is *not* Christ. Christ — the same Christ who became man, was crucified, and was raised — preexisted Creation, which is only possible if the *man* Christ is both man *and God*.)

There are additional passages that speak to Christ's preexistence; for example:

| John 17:5 |
| --- |
| [Jesus said,] "And now, Father, glorify me in your own presence with the glory that I had with you before the world existed" |

| John 1:15 |
| --- |
| John bore witness about [The Word which became flesh], and cried out, "This was he of whom I said, 'He who comes after me ranks before me, because he was before me.'" |

| John 8:58 |
| --- |
| Jesus said to them, "Truly, truly, I say to you, before Abraham was, I Am." |

While these don't necessarily argue *against* the "beginning" in John 1 being later, they certainly *support* that a reading of John 1 as referring to The Beginning is valid. In fact, this is true even if one denies that the Logos of John 1:1 is the *person* of Christ, because numerous Scriptures speak of *some* sort of preexistence of something, and any alternate interpretation of those passages would also work with John 1:1.

Now, one argument is that John 1:1 and 1 John 1:1 are inconsistent. But as in the preceding paragraph, if we take John 1 as indicating that Christ has existed since the Beginning of Creation, then there is no trouble at all applying this same meaning to 1 John 1.

Perhaps most compelling, however, is when we consider how John's original audience would have read his Gospel. That original audience wouldn't be reading out of a collected volume where John is sandwiched between Luke and Acts. They would have been reading John's Gospel *by itself*. In that context, the most natural reading is either that vv1-4 are referring to an *absolute* beginning, giving context to a narrative that does indeed skip ahead at v5, or that v1 is a deliberate reference to Genesis 1:1. Of course, both possibilities result in the same interpretation. There's simply no context to imply otherwise, which is *not* the case in Mark (1:1: "The beginning *of the gospel of Jesus Christ*) or Luke (1:2's "those who from the beginning were eyewitnesses" correlates with the earlier part of the sentence in 1:1, "the things that have been accomplished among us"). Frankly, an interpretation as other than The Beginning is *eisegetical*; it's reading something into the text that simply isn't there.

Therefore, I conclude that any interpretation of "beginning" in John 1:1 as *other* than The Beginning is of no notable benefit, and is detrimental to *theological* consistency. Since there is no other overt reason to prefer one reading over the other, I am far inclined to side with the reading which is most theologically beneficial and is that accepted by the majority of Christians.

---

¹ Yes, yes, not everyone agrees with this assertion. Personally, however, I've always found *pro*-Trinitarian arguments to be straight-forward and for the most part "obvious" and refutations of anti-Trinitarian arguments easily made. Whereas I find the case *against* Trinitarianism feels like it's having to work to distort the meaning of Scripture. Anyway, that's your disclaimer that this answer is written from a pro-Trinitarian perspective. Plenty of words have been written on the subject elsewhere that I don't need to rehash here.

Comment: Doesn't the same issue with John 1:3 apply to Col 1? 'All' is ambiguous, especially given St. Paul's list (thrones, dominions, and so on). Compare Ephesians 1, which is similar but more explicitly all about the new beginning.

Comment: Worth noting John 1:15 and John 8:58 are grammatically ambiguous. 8:58 is so ambiguous it could even be talking about Abraham's future coming to be!

Comment: Important to note ancient Jewish belief that the name of the Messiah (Christ) existed before the foundation of the earth. Cf. the Babylonion Talmud. This is an obvious possible target of John 17:5.

Comment: "Whereas I find the case against Trinitarianism feels like it's having to work to distort the meaning of Scripture." You mean like having to distort phrases like 'the Father is greater than I', the only true God is the Father, 'I am a man who has heard things from God', 'Jesus of Nazareth is a man who was certified by God', 'Why do you call me good? No one is good but God' and so on, and so on? I don't like popping up proof-texts like this, but you're really preaching to the choir here I think. ;)

Comment: "John 1:1 is radically different than the start of the other Gospels" Are you sure this isn't just assuming what you are supposed to show? If you think John 1:1 is about the new beginning, how different is it from Mark 1 (which also then segues immediately to John the Baptist)?

Comment: ...but v15 also says "[Christ is] the firstborn of all creation". And there's an awful lot of "all"s being flung around for them to be somehow contextually limited. I'm not sure to what specifically in Ephesians 1 you're referring, though Christ *acting* "before the foundation of the world" certainly suggests preexistence. As for John 1 being "radically different"... really? It's highly poetic and clearly speaking of "deep" concepts.

Comment: Ya, but Col 1:18 *repeats* firstborn and says "He is the beginning and firstborn *from among the dead*", a clear reference to the resurrection and so the new creation.

Comment: I agree with you that John 1's prologue is poetic, hence we should be *very tentative* about going from a line in John 1 to sweeping theological conclusions. A particular interpretation of John 1:1 or 1:14 aren't good bases for theological conclusions. Rather, we should ask "How does this interpretation fit with the rest of John?"

Comment: If you think Eph 1:4 means Christ's literal preexistence, does that mean we preexisted too?

Comment: Eph 1:18-23 is what I'm specifically referring to. He's far above 'all' rule and power and dominion, God has put 'everything' under his feet and put him as head over 'everything'. The use of these terms is clearly about the new creation.

Comment: Re: "firstborn", why can't He be *both*? Besides, John 1:1 makes ***no*** sense as the beginning of the New Creation, which is yet to come. That would make vv1-5 *predictive*, with a time skip *backward* at v6, which is even worse than you claim for the interpretation of "beginning" as The Beginning. And you'd have to apply that to Ephesians, also, which contradicts "predestined". OTOH, if Jesus is God, and outside of time, there is no problem.

Comment: No! The new beginning has a definitive start with Jesus' conception, birth, and (most obviously for John) ministry. Again, look at how Jesus himself uses 'beginning' in John.

Comment: Sure, and if Jesus is God, you have a pile-up of theological problems and mysteries that have to be posited. No problem indeed.

Comment: Re 'firstborn', sure, he *could* be both. But we *known* Paul is using it in the sense of the new beginning, whereas the other use is ambiguous.

Comment: Heb 1:2 'world' is a questionable interpretation. Literally, 'the ages'. See commentary here https://www.revisedenglishversion.com/Hebrews/chapter1/2

Comment: @OneGodtheFather, but which ages? *All* of them? Time itself? (Which physics tells us is synonymous with "the material universe" *anyway*...) That would imply that Christ is *outside time*, just like I said earlier. And your "pile-up of theological problems and mysteries" really aren't issues to anyone that understands the dual nature of Jesus in His Incarnation.

Comment: I understand Trinitarian theology pretty well, including various theories about Jesus' dual-natures. For your question, see the last paragraph of the discussion in link above to Hebrews 1:2.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather  Heb 1:2 isn't questionable - it's plain wrong, some even have *universe!* Another good example of T's using such verses to proclaim their truth using *wrong* translations. No wonder the author doesn't make sense of claims against T, when the evidence used by T's is non-existent or fabricated. T's might as well quote the Message bible!

Comment: @steveowen, such an interesting coincidence this conversation is happening at the same time https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/92126 was asked. Now, obviously, there are many "Christians" with assuredly heretical theology (the U/T debate is proof enough of that). I find it hard to believe that the majority of Christians throughout the majority of history have all been *that* degree of heretical, however.

Comment: @Matthew It isn’t hard to imagine if God allowed His perfect beginning in the Garden to go severely wrong, (there are good reasons for that) then it’s no trouble to consider the *church* has gone terribly wrong too. That most of it is deceived is simply another sign of the god of this world doing his thing.